# Create column based on another dataframe

Tags: r

I have what seems a simple requirement, but I can't seem to achieve the desired result. My dataframes are rather large, so I will just give a screenshot:[image]

What I want is: `if ps2c$ps == present2$pn then ps2c$sf == present2$sf`.

If it is not clear, for every `ps2c$ps` there is a `present2$pn` (present2 is just the mean data).

Comment: A screenshot? Are you kidding me? ;-) Seriously, just *paste* the output from `head(ps2c)` and `head(present2)` into your Q, select the pasted code/output, and click the code button in the toolbar (the one that looks like braces `{}`) or press `Ctrl+k` to have your code formatted appropriately.

Comment: My data frame is massive, but I will bear your suggestion in mind.

Comment: but `head()` only shows the first few lines - my point was, if you can show a screenshot you can show the code and output from `head()`.

Comment: dput(head(ps2c)) gives you a representation of the 6 first lines of the data frame that we can run without editing anything. Alternatively, you can construct a toy dataset to show what you want.

Comment: @Joris - that is a great observation, one which helps facilitate providing small snippets of data for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't supply test data, but something like the following might work:

```
ps2c$sf <- present2$sf[match(ps2c$ps, present2$pn)]
```

Comment: I am working with a dataset with 72 million observations, and I was trying to do this task using a not-straightforward routine which involved the foreach function. I tested it for about 1/1000 of my dataset and it took more than 20 minutes. With your solution it took a second for the whole dataset. I can't thank you enough. R really rocks, I can't wait to be good at it!