# How to create column based on subsets from another dataframe with differing number of rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe based on subsets from a different dataframe.

```
df<-data.frame(Name=c('Team 1','Team 1','Team 1', 'Team 2', 'Team 3','Team 3', 'Team 3','Team 4','Team 4'), In=c(8,25,2,2,1,3,3,9,24), Out=c(40,40,20,3,20,1,1,100,1), Group=c(1,1,1,-1,NA,NA,NA,1,1))

df1<-data.frame(Name=c('Team 1','Team 1','Team 1', 'Team 2','Team 2','Team 2','Team 2', 'Team 3','Team 3', 'Team 3','Team 4','Team 4'), In=c(8,25,2,2,1,3,3,9,24,35,14,19), Out=c(40,40,20,3,20,1,1,1,18,29,31,11))

df1$Group<-''

a<-subset(df,Group=='-1')
b<-subset(df,Group=='1')

head(df)
    Name In Out Group
1 Team 1  8  40     1
2 Team 1 25  40     1
3 Team 1  2  20     1
4 Team 2  2   3    -1
5 Team 3  1  20    NA
6 Team 3  3   1    NA
7 Team 3  3   1    NA
8 Team 4  9 100     1
9 Team 4 24   1     1

head(df1)
     Name In Out Group
1  Team 1  5   4      
2  Team 1  5   4      
3  Team 1 22   2      
4  Team 2 21  13      
5  Team 2 14  21      
6  Team 2 13  11      
7  Team 2 13  21      
8  Team 3 19  13      
9  Team 3 21  18      
10 Team 3 13  29      
11 Team 4 14  31      
12 Team 4 19  11
```

I found what I thought was my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619091/create-column-based-on-another-dataframe), and this way doesn't use subsets, but it also doesn't work due to the differing numbering of rows.

```
df1$Group <- df$Group[match(df$Name,df1$Name)]
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Group", value = c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1,  : 
replacement has 9 rows, data has 12
```

What I want for my outcome is to create a column ('Group') in df1 so that if the "Name" is found in subset 'a', then it receives a '-1', and if the name is found in subset 'b', then it receives a '1', and everything else that does not fit the category is either left blank or 'NA'.

Example of wanted outcome:

```
 head(df1)
     Name In Out Group
1  Team 1  5   4     1
2  Team 1  5   4     1
3  Team 1 22   2     1
4  Team 2 21  13    -1
5  Team 2 14  21    -1
6  Team 2 13  11    -1
7  Team 2 13  21    -1
8  Team 3 19  13    NA
9  Team 3 21  18    NA
10 Team 3 13  29    NA
11 Team 4 14  31     1
12 Team 4 19  11     1
```

The datasets I am working with are still being added to, and are very large, and so it's nonsensical to do it manually. I've been stuck on this for a while, so hopefully one of you can help me figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: `df1$Group <- ifelse(df1$Name %in% a$Name, -1, ifelse(df1$Name %in% b$Name, 1, NA))`

Comment: That seemed embarrassingly easy, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JasonAizkalns pretty much nailed it, but I'll try to expand on what he wrote.

```
df1$Group <- ifelse(df1$Name %in% a$Name, -1, ifelse(df1$Name %in% b$Name, 1, NA))
```

`ifelse()` is a very useful function. It takes three arguments - the condition, the first output, and the 'else' output.  As you can see, he's used another `ifelse()` in the 'else' condition.

As regards `%in%`, from the documentation:

> %in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand.

So, putting it together:

If `df1$Name` has an indexed match in `a$Name`, assign `df1$Group` -1.

If `df1$Name` has an indexed match in `b$Name`, assign `df1$Group` a 1.

Else, assign `df1$Group` 'NA'.

Hope that's clear.